# DidexitRegion event is never called with app in background

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I am using altbeacon library.
In mainapplication class i am extending Bootstrapnotifier,
And when a didEnterRegion is called I call fire an intent and start anforeground service for a class that extends BeaconConsumer and looks for entry and exit events. 
The problem is main application detects didEnterRegion events when app is in background but didExitRegion is never called even after waiting for 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing region beacon monitoring in both a custom Android Application class and in a foreground service is likely to cause complex lifecycle problems, so if possible I would simplify the solution by leaving all the monitoring logic in the custom Application class.  You can still start your foreground service -- so long as the foreground service is running the same custom Application class will stay alive as well.

If you rally want to get monitoring working in the service class in addition to the application class, I'd suggest testing that you get any beacon events at all including entry events, which are much easier to test.  Simply launch your application manually with no beacons on, then turn on a beacon and see if your foreground service gets a didEnterRegion callback.  You may find that it does not, which means you need to troubleshoot this setup.  Make sure your monitorNotifier is added correctly.